# what is the product of this reaction and mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry

![picture from national chemistry Olympiad]

[image]

I cant get the mechanism.
Answer shows there will be formation of keto group.
But how?

As I can understand the $\ce{H^+}$ is going to attack the $\ce{O}$ and can remove the $\ce{CH3}$ groups forming two adjacent alcohols which may join to form keton.
I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism to convert acetal to ketone in acid based hydrolysis is in following steps-

- Protonation of (1) to make OCH3 a good leaving group forming  (2)
- O lone pair allows LG to leave forming oxonium ion and alcohol(3)
- Water nucleophile attacks C of C=O (3) to give (4)
- Base removes proton to give (5).
- Reprotonates (5) to make OCH3  a better leaving group(6).
- CH3OH leaves to give (7)
- Base deproronates to give ketone (8)

**Note :In this scheme, the base, B:, could be R-O-R, R-OH, H2O or the conjugate base of the acid catalyst**

[image]

**References:**

- http://www.chem.ucalgary.ca/courses/353/exams/3513/353w05/353fin05me.html
- https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/aldket1.htm

Comment: Base is confusing. It is actually water.

Comment: that was awesome! in the 5 step it will be h2o Not base.

Comment: @RoulKessels  In this scheme, the base, B:, could be R-O-R, R-OH, H2O or the conjugate base of the acid catalyst

Comment: @SharifulIslam In this scheme, the base, B:, could be R-O-R, R-OH, H2O or the conjugate base of the acid catalyst

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the oxigen is protonated, water enters, methanol leaves and another $\ce{H^+}$ is released.
Then the oxigen of the other $\ce{CH3O}$ group is protonated, the keto group is formed while the methanol leaves and $\ce{H^+}$ is released.

Edit:

The first part results in:

[image]

and $\ce{CH3OH}$.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by water enters?

Comment: I have edited. I do not have a proper drawing program with me to draw the whole mechanism

Comment: in the first step the lower O will be protonated,forming OH+(CH3).Then the CH3- Will be removed and OH+ WILl become alcohol group.From where does CH3-gets Oh-?And why the same will not occur for the upper och3 group?

Comment: No. Water enters and methanol is removed. Then the other -OMe is protonated and methanol is removed and the ketone is formed.

Comment: I have found an image

Comment: yes the image is from http://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/Handouts/ElecPush/ep-mechanisms.htm

Comment: thatz so great!